# Get month name using start date and end date?

Tags: php, date

```
$startDate = "2014-03-01";
$endDate= "2014-05-25";
```

Result required: March, April, May;

Answer (score 5):

for that PHP delivers the DatePeriod object. Just have a look at the following example.

```
$period = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime('2014-03-01'),
    DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month'),
    new DateTime('2014-05-25')
);

foreach ($period as $month) {
    echo strftime('%B', $month->format('U'));
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why people always favor complicated, hard to understand solutions. People new to PHP will sink in OOP approach faster than rock.

Comment: @rm-rf OOP makes your life a lot easier, and the more complex a problem becomes, the easier it is to solve with OOP. So please never ever advise against using OOP, the more when a beginner is concerned

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution is to parse each day and check it month:

```
$startDate = "2014-03-01";
$endDate = "2014-05-25";

$start = strtotime($startDate);
$end = strtotime($endDate);

$result = array();
while ( $start <= $end )
{
    $month = date("M", $start);

    if( !in_array($month, $result) )
        $result[] = $month;

    $start += 86400;
}

print_r($result);
```

I believe it can be done much efficient by new OOP (DateTime object) approach, but this is fast and no-brain if you need to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $date = date('F',strtotime($startDate));
```

For full month representation (ie Januaray, February, etc)

```
  $date = date('M',strtotime($startDate));
```

For abbreviated...(ie Jan, Feb, Mar)

[REFERENCE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

If you wanna echo out those months in between based on two dates....

```
 $d = "2014-03-01";
 $startDate = new DateTime($d);
 $endDate = new DateTime("2014-05-01");

 function diffInMonths(DateTime $date1, DateTime $date2)
 {
    $diff =  $date1->diff($date2);
    $months = $diff->y * 12 + $diff->m + $diff->d / 30;
    return (int) round($months);
 }

  $t = diffInMonths($startDate, $endDate);

  for($i=0;$i<$t+1;$i++){
    echo date('F',strtotime($d. '+'.$i.' Months'));
  }
```

[PHP SANDBOX EXAMPLE](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fb56105352259c5505707e0f4480f480c5b0a481)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$startDate = "2014-03-01";
echo date('F',strtotime($startDate));
?
```

Comment: Please explain rather than posting your code. We are here to teach people to be better at what they do. Give a man a fish...